# javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException appears when trying to register spring boot rest application in Eureka

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I am trying to register my spring boot rest service in Eureka server. My service is registering well in the Eureka server and after few seconds it will throw an javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException. But still I can see the service that is registered in the Eureka. Can anybody please explain me why I am getting this error.

application.properties of my rest service.

```
spring.application.name=currency-conversion-service
server.port=8100
eureka.client.service-url.default-zone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Starter class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class CurrencyConversionServiceApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(CurrencyConversionServiceApplication.class, args);
}
```

}

application.yml of my Eureka server

```
server:
port: 8761

info:
  component: Discovery Server

logging:
  level:
    root: WARN
    com.testapp: WARN
    com.netflix.hystrix: WARN
  file: /home/ubuntu/socket/logs/eureka.log

eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

---

```
spring:
  profiles: peer # not standalone
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: 127.0.0.1
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

I am getting below error

```
    2018-08-11 19:39:15.890 ERROR 22622 --- [tbeatExecutor-0] 
    c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error

javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: null  

at com.netflix.discovery.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider.readFrom(DiscoveryJerseyProvider.java:110) ~[eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]

com.netflix.discovery.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider.readFrom(DiscoveryJerseyProvider.java:110) ~[eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]

at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:634) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:586) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.sendHeartBeat(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:105) ~[eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92) [eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.java:73) ~[eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89) [eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92) [eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:89) ~[eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89) [eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92) [eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:120) [eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89) [eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92) [eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) [eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89) [eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.renew(DiscoveryClient.java:846) [eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$HeartbeatThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1399) [eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_144]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_144]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_144]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_144]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_144]
2018-08-11 19:39:15.891  WARN 22622 --- [tbeatExecutor-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient    : Request execution failed with message: null
2018-08-11 19:39:15.895 ERROR 22622 --- [tbeatExecutor-0] 
c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: null
at com.netflix.discovery.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider.readFrom(DiscoveryJerseyProvider.java:110) ~[eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:634) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:586) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.sendHeartBeat(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:105) ~[eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92) [eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.java:73) ~[eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89) [eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92) [eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.executeOnNewServer(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:118) ~[eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:79) ~[eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89) [eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92) [eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:120) [eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89) [eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92) [eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) [eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89) [eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.renew(DiscoveryClient.java:846) [eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$HeartbeatThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1399) [eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_144]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_144]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_144]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_144]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_144]
2018-08-11 19:39:15.895  WARN 22622 --- [tbeatExecutor-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient    : Request execution failed with message: null
2018-08-11 19:39:15.896 ERROR 22622 --- [tbeatExecutor-0] 
com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_CURRENCY-
CONVERSION-SERVICE/192.168.0.100:currency-conversion-service:8100 - 
was unable to send heartbeat!
com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:112) ~[eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89) ~[eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92) ~[eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) ~[eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89) ~[eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.renew(DiscoveryClient.java:846) ~[eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$HeartbeatThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1399) [eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_144]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_144]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_144]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_144]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_144]
```

Comment: No, but 'defaultZone' is a map key and is therefore case sensitive.

Comment: Do I need to change this defaultZone ? Can you please explain bit

Comment: eureka.client.service-url.default-zone should change to defaultZone

Comment: I changed to defaultZone. Now it is  eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka. But still the issue is there